# facebook and gmail not open login page in safari in simulator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, gmail, google-signin

I have integrated facebook and gmail in my app but when i redirect user to safari for login i am not able to open facebook or google page for loginin safari in simulator. it gives me error like **"safari can not open the page because it can not establish secure connection to the server.**"
Any one knows what is solution to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Varun, can you check if the date and time in simulator is correct? Sometime a wrong date and time in simulator can cause the secure connections to break

Answer (score 2):

Below are common issues in such cases

- Disable 'Auto Proxy discovery' in proxy settings of your Mac
- You are behind a proxy
- You are using a Antivirus which has WebShield of similar feature enabled. Disable the antivirus and try again
- Your simulator's date & time are not sync to current date. Certificates don't validate fine when system date is skewed
- Rebooting the simulator also at times help

Below are the threads you should look into

[Can't visit website on iOS Simulator—'This Connection Is Not Private'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980164/cant-visit-website-on-ios-simulator-this-connection-is-not-private)

[iOS simulator can't access any URL and shows the error "This connection is not private"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682379/ios-simulator-cant-access-any-url-and-shows-the-error-this-connection-is-not-p)

[iOS Simulator not works on https, all https are evaluated as not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064807/ios-simulator-not-works-on-https-all-https-are-evaluated-as-not-trusted)

[Can't use HTTP in iOS 8 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654679/cant-use-http-in-ios-8-simulator)

[iPhone simulator cannot connect to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542706/iphone-simulator-cannot-connect-to-internet)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by disabling Avast Web Shield.

Answer (score 1):

I have Avast Antivirus installed and adding facebook url to the configuration of the internet scanning service allowed me to fix this problem.