# iOS simulator can't access any URL and shows the error "This connection is not private"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, safari, ios-simulator

I've encountered a problem where my iPhone Simulator can't access any of the websites on SAFARI. I am also unable to call any API from my application.

The error shown by SAFARI is either of the two mentioned below:
"**This connection is not private**"

Refer Screenshot
[image: Refer Screenshot]

OR

"**Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server**"

Refer Screenshot
[image: Refer Screenshot]

I have done some research on this issue and have come across a few different solutions. But all of them suggest me to:

- Uncheck "web-sheilding" in my anti-virus software; OR
- Turn on the "Allow HTTP Loads" in Simulator>Settings>Developer; OR
- "Erase content and settings" and restart the simulator

None of these solutions are working for me.
Could anyone suggest what the problem here might be?

I'm using Xcode v9.2 and Simulator with iOS11.2.

Comment: Please visit this  [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8140123) for more detail.

Comment: I've visited this thread and they just suggest to change the network. I've been using the same network for a long while now and it has never caused this problem before. I have even tried changing my wifi network but I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you using any proxy tool or VPN on mac

Comment: Nothing of that sort.

Comment: @Pramit Tewari did you set Allow HTTP Loads to YES in your info.plist ?

Comment: I tried that when i thought that the problem was in my app (did not help). But actually the problem I'm facing is that The SAFARI browser in my simulator can't reach any website. It's not app specific. Even the secure sites (with https://) are not loading.

Comment: This indicates you have an HTTP proxy, kernel extension, malware, or other configuration that is interfering with the ability to create a secure connection. If you are inside a corporate network your IT department may also be attempting to MITM all connections.

Comment: Ditto proxy setting. I had the same and disabled the corporate proxy and all sites worked again.

Comment: Something was so weird for me. If I connect with Lan simulator, it can load pages, but when on wifi, it does not. I checked, and the only difference was in Wi-Fi network details -> Proxies. I turned off the Auto proxy discovery. And after that works well. Maybe it is the same in your case.